# ASP.Net MVC 6 Windows Authentication Custom Authorization custom role check from database

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create an Intranet application with ASP.Net MVC 6

I am using windows authentication I want set different rules based from a database table

for example if I want to restrict access of some users from a function or controller

```
    // GET: TestingAuths
    [Authorize(Roles ="administrator")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.MyTestingAuth.ToList());
    }
```

how can I check that the user logged in has the role Administrator from my database Role table.
Here is a solution but it is not for ASP.Net MVC 6: http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC

I want a solution for ASP.Net MVC 6

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have this working by now but for the Intranet I am working on while learning MVC and .Net Core I have used Claims-Based Authorisation dependent on a database value held against the Person.

I approached it this way, which no doubt can be improved but hopefully that will come in time.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddMvc(config =>
 {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
 })

 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
    options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Administrator"));
 });

 services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
 {
    options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;
 });

 var connection = etc etc;
 services.AddDbContext<IntranetContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

 services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformer, ClaimsTransformer>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseClaimsTransformation(async (context) =>
        {
            IClaimsTransformer transformer = context.Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IClaimsTransformer>();
            return await transformer.TransformAsync(context);
        });

        app.UseStatusCodePages();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**ClaimsTransformer.cs**

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
{
    private readonly IntranetContext dbcontext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ClaimsTransformer" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Also to be written.</param>
    public ClaimsTransformer(IntranetContext context)
    {
        this.dbcontext = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manages claims against the ClaimsPrincipal for Authenticated Users
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Also to be written.</param>
    /// <returns>Still to be written.</returns>
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
    {
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = null;

        foreach (var i in context.Principal.Identities)
        {
            if (i.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity))
            {
                windowsIdentity = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)i;
            }
        }

        if (windowsIdentity != null)
        {
            var username = windowsIdentity.Name.Remove(0, 6);
            var appUser = this.dbcontext.Person.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == username);

            if (appUser != null)
            {
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Id", Convert.ToString(appUser.Id), ClaimValueTypes.Integer));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Fullname", appUser.Firstname + ' ' + appUser.Surname, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Firstname", appUser.Firstname, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Surname", appUser.Surname, ClaimValueTypes.String));

                if (appUser.Administrator)
                {
                    ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Administrator", "1", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Person newPerson = new Person();
                newPerson.Username = username;
                newPerson.Firstname = username.Split('.')[0].ToString().ToTitleCase();
                newPerson.Surname = username.Split('.')[1].ToString().ToTitleCase();
                newPerson.LocationId = 1;
                newPerson.CreatedBy = 1;
                newPerson.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                newPerson.Email = username + "@mycompany.com";
                this.dbcontext.Add(newPerson);
                await this.dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

                appUser = this.dbcontext.Person.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == username);
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Id", Convert.ToString(appUser.Id), ClaimValueTypes.Integer));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Fullname", appUser.Firstname + ' ' + appUser.Surname, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Firstname", appUser.Firstname, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Surname", appUser.Surname, ClaimValueTypes.String));
            }
        }

        return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
    }
}
```

> On any controller I can then apply [Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]

I hope that works for you.

Thanks.

Comment: This would be greatly improved by some inline comments.

Comment: I will try @Gusdor but being a novice still I don't completely understand everything going on here and rather compiled it based on SO and MSDN research, in particular the asp-net/core site.

Comment: no drama. I spent a bit of time on it and have a rough idea of the key elements. I'll assist where I can.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your identity/authentication provider would provide role claims within the claims identity (if that's in your control)

But, another way is to write your own AuthorizationHandler which intercepts mvc calls.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<CustomAuthorizationRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    private readonly AppDBContext _context;
    public CustomAuthorizationRequirement(AppDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, CustomAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var isValid = false;

        //perform any checks you want here i.e. check for authorization filters and validate against your database roles
        //Due to the 2 different versions of AuthorizationContext I have hard referenced this
        if(context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext)
        {
            //Get the MVC authorization context
            var authContext = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext)context.Resource;

            //Find the AuthorizeAttribute from the given function
            var authAttribute = authContext.Filters.OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            foreach(var role in authAttribute.Roles.Split(new char[] {','}))
            {
                var isInRole = _context.Set<ApplicationUser>().Count(u => u.UserName == context.User.Name && u.UserRoles.Contains(role) > 0);
                if (isInRole)
                    isValid = true;

            }
        }


        if (isValid )
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        else
            context.Fail();
    }
}
```

And to register it:

```
var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new CustomAuthorizationRequirement ()).Build();
var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvcCore(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy)));
```

Comment: can you add more info how do I check for authorization filters from database or roles from database

Comment: How you sort/manage your user/roles model is up to you..... but i have added an edit to show a rough example of this

Comment: Can you give step by step example I am new

Comment: It looks like it should work to me, but it's built a _policy_. So, I think you're going to be using `[Authorize(Policy="administrator")]` rather than `[Authorize(Roles ="administrator")]`

Answer (score -2):

Rather than do a roles check you should look at policies in code.

A handler for a requirement can take DI elements in their constructor, so you could register your RoleRepository in DI then take it in the handler constructor. Then use a parameterised requirement to configure your policies.

So, for example;

```
public class MyRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public MyRoleRequirement(string roles)
    {
        Roles = roles;
    }

    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's assume your have your roles repository as inheriting from IRolesRepository with a IsInRole(string roles, ClaimsPrincipal user) function. In your handler you'd do something like

```
public class MyRoleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRoleRequirement>
{
    IRolesRepository _rolesRepository;

    public MyRoleAuthorizationHandler(IRolesRepository rolesRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, 
                                   MyRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (_rolesRepository.IsInRole(requirement.Roles, context.User)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just configure your policies and handler in startup.cs in ConfigureServices(), and remember to register your roles repository in the DI system and away it goes.

That may look like

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Administrators", policy =>
    { 
        policy.Requirements.Add(new MyRolesRequirement("Administrator));
    });
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyRolesAuthorizationHandler>();
```

[Code based policies](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html) are in the documentation as is [DI in handlers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/dependencyinjection.html)

Note that this code was done in the input box rather than VS so it may not compile :)

Comment: Dear Blowdart, can you please give step by step and detailed example because I am new to this

Comment: Well, it's right as far as it goes, but (a) it fails to explain _why_ you shouldn't do a Role check _[really, why do we _have_ roles and no apparent way to modify them?]_, and (b) it is inconsistently using `MyRole` and `MyRoles`, so it's obviously not actually tested code. @blowdart has explained all this better, elsewhere, but it took me days to find.